# How do I make an AAB file?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I have went into android studio and the option to build one isn't there, I went to an earlier version it said I needed a newer version of gradle, I looked up how to do that and then it gave me a result than only works in an earlier version, so I went to said earlier version AND IT DOESNT HAVE THE OPTION TO BUILD TO AN AAB FILE. I feel like I have just wasted 25$. How do I make a signed AAB file from an APK?

Comment: Please provide the versions of Android Studio and gradle which you are using.

Comment: Did you read [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-your-first-app-bundle-bbcd228bf631) from the Android Developers team?

Answer (score 2):

To generate a signed AAB file, Goto

> Build->generate Signed Bundle/APK...

[image]

Here select `Android App Bundle` and click `Next`

[image]

This dialog box will be open next.

[image]

Here either create a new Key store path by selecting `Create new...` or `Choose existing...` to select existing one.

The `Create new...` opens the below dialog, enter the details here and click `OK`

[image]

Now click `Next`, and Generate Signed Bundle or APK dialog opens and click Finish.

[image]